# UITextField getting from paste

Tags: uitextfield, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

When I pasted a text into my UITextField with attributed.text the font of the UITextField was also changed to the font that was pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding beginediting and endediting solved the problem

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrUrl = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world"];

[attrUrl beginEditing];
[attrUrl addAttribute:.....];

[attrUrl endEditing];
```